# Save Form data from Popover in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

```js
   var App = angular.module('myApp', []);
   App.controller('myPopoverCtrl',
    function($scope){
      $scope.myPopover = {
        isOpen: false,
        open: function open() {
            $scope.myPopover.isOpen = true;
          },
        close: function close() {
           // alert('hi');
            $scope.myPopover.isOpen = false;
        }
      };

      $scope.SaveNotes  = function() { 
      console.log('hi');
      console.log($scope.noteText);
      //getting undefined here
      return false;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "App">
<a uib-popover-template="'AddNote.html'" 
           popover-title="AddNote" 
           popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"
           ng-controller="myPopoverCtrl"
           popover-is-open="myPopover.isOpen"
           ng-click="myPopover.open()">Add
        </a>
 </div>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="AddNote.html">
  <div>
   <textarea class="form-control height-auto" 
   ng-model="noteText" 
   placeholder="This is a new note" ></textarea>
   <input class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" 
   type="button" 
   ng- click="SaveNotes();" value="Save">
  </div>
 </script>
```

I have web a page where i  have a button and when click the button popover appears.In that popover i have textarea but when i click save button i want get the text in my controller but i am getting undefined using $scope.modelname

How can i get that data?

Comment: put your code on jsfiddle

Comment: i did but getting some script issue can u plz check

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a modal rather than a popover like so, as a popover is really just to display text :-

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: $rootScope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'views/myTemplate.html',
                    size: 'md'
                }).result.then(function(result) {
                $scope.result = result;
            });
```

This is what it's designed for more info [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: its for popup.i need uib-popover